Unable to mount or fix my Apple Raid mirrored volume
I have 2 identical external 2T disks, mirrored using diskutility.
Yesterday I realised that this volume was not mounted.
I started diskutility to see what was going on and it came up as a blank screen. Tried multiple times until it eventually showed a disk info loading spinner.
Eventually it showed my disks, and the raid volume, but no other useful info. Verify threw an error that I can't remember.
I then started using the terminal.
diskutil appleRaid list
showed that one of the disks was rebuilding.... 20 hours later it is rebuilt but still won't mount.
diskutil list
gives the following (trimmed to show just the disks with the issue)
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID ⁨⁩                        2.0 TB     disk3s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk3s3

/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk4
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_RAID ⁨⁩                        2.0 TB     disk4s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot ⁨Boot OS X⁩               134.2 MB   disk4s3

/dev/disk6 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                 Apple_APFS                        +2.0 TB     disk6

/dev/disk7 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +ERROR      disk7
                                 Physical Store disk6
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨MediaTwo⁩                ERROR      disk7s1

diskutil volumeVerify disk6
shows errors as follows:
Started file system verification on disk6
Verifying storage system
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x /dev/disk4
Checking the container superblock
Checking the space manager
Checking the space manager free queue trees
Checking the object map
Checking volume /dev/rdisk6s1
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the fsroot tree
error: directory record (id 19): invalid hash (0x0, expected 0x14489a) of name (shutdown_time)
error: directory record (id 22922): invalid hash (0x0, expected 0x3c39c7) of name (NSIRD_mediaanalysisd_3J7qIv)

... Similar lines removed

error: directory record (id 31262): invalid hash (0x0, expected 0x2ae08b) of name (DB84492D-45C4-421C-8ADE-87682424AB46)
error: directory record (id 31262): invalid hash (0x0, expected 0x243010) of name (E637CFBE-FE99-4CEF-B8FF-5B122D5CCA8C)
error: directory record (id 378685): invalid hash (0x0, expected 0xfa1fa) of name (426AF3BB-CA79-4E4D-B3D3-59B09DCD5AD2_1_102_o.jpeg)
error: directory valence check: directory (oid 0x60492): nchildren (9321) does not match drec count (9320) 
error: directory record (id 592626): invalid hash (0x0, expected 0x238bff) of name (Asset-tmp.plist)
error: directory record (id 592626): invalid hash (0x0, expected 0x253850) of name (HistoryToken-tmp.plist)
error: directory valence check: directory (oid 0x90af2): nchildren (47) does not match drec count (45) 
error: dstream (id 1229027) does not have an associated dstream id object
Checking the extent ref tree
error: (oid 0x233709) apfs_extentref: btn: invalid o_oid (0x23371f)
error: (oid 0x233709) apfs_extentref: btn: invalid o_type (0x40000002, expected 0x40000003)
error: (oid 0x233709) apfs_extentref: btn: invalid o_subtype (0xb, expected 0xf)
Extent ref tree is invalid
The volume /dev/rdisk6s1 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired
Verifying allocated space
Performing deferred repairs
error: Unable to perform deferred repairs without full space verification
The container /dev/disk4 could not be verified completely

I've run fsck_apfs on the volume (disk7) and container (disk6) to no avail.
How can I recover this? In theory I have 2 disks with a copy of my data, but the RAID array seems to be corrupt in some way.
If I unplug one of the disks then I get exactly the same error when running diskutil verifyVolume or fsck_apfs

I've got to ask the obvious question... how old is your last backup of this data?

I have time machine backups. Although running up time machine does not show some of the files that I know should be on this volume (photos library, Adobe bridge library and videos mostly) I don't know why. Is there a way to get time machine to tell you when and what was backed up?
